# How can I duplicate the script as well as a sheet/tab in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to duplicate a template sheet on a daily basis, but the template has a script attached to it. How do I ensure that, when I duplicate the template to create that day's document, the script is duplicated as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make a copy of the entire spreadsheet as well as the google app script associated with it, then below code will do:

```
DriveApp.getFileById("SPREADSHEET_KEY").makeCopy();
```

Comment: Is there anyway do duplicate just one tab with the associated script? I'm hoping to use just one doc and duplicate the tabs on a daily basis. The template tab that I'm using includes two timestamping columns, which I'd like to retain in all duplicates.